# What is the difference between platex and pdflatex?

Tags: platex

I just learned that there is *another* latex program called *platex*. But I can't find a good definition of what platex is and why I might want to use it.

Comment: Run `texdoc platex`. If you can't read the pdf you probably don't want to use platex.

Comment: At first I thought this was a joke, since "Platex" is a brand name for things such as brassieres. But it turns out that pLaTeX exists, with information to be found here: http://www.nongnu.org/fcp/platex/platex.html

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, could you please post a bit of information?

Comment: @vy32 Ulrike just meant to see that it was in Japanese, she didn't mean you to read the text.

Comment: Sorry that many of you can't read platex.pdf; I (one of the maintainers) started to work on English translation (platex-en.pdf; not currently built but you can build it by `make platex-en.pdf` using Makefile), see https://github.com/texjporg/platex

Comment: @RobtAll The "platex" you found is not our Japanese pLaTeX (which is the one included in TeX Live), sorry

Answer (score 8):

LaTeX is a set of tex macros, and (almost) the same set of macros can be used over several variant tex engines to build a format, usually named by adding `la` somewhere to the engine names.

The main engines and their latex formats are

- tex (**-**) Classic TeX, LaTeX now assumes an extended TeX and formats using this engine are not built.
- etex (**latex**)  Extended LaTeX with more registers and useful extra primitives such as `\dimexpr` (etex and pdftex are the same executable these days, with different options)
- pdftex (**pdflatex**) version of etex producing pdf rather than dvi.
- xetex (**xelatex**) Extended TeX using OpenType fonts and Unicode input.
- luatex (**lualatex**) Extended TeX using OpenType fonts and Unicode input and tight integration to Lua.
- dviluatex (**dvilualatex**) Almost never used, this is luatex configured to make a dvi rather than pdf but few (if any) drivers can process the resulting dvi files if luatex features are used.
- ptex (**-**) Japanese variant of TeX, with extended support for vertical writing orientation and Japanese encodings.
- eptex (**platex**) Version of ptex with etex features
- uptex (**-**) Extended variant of ptex supporting Unicode
- euptex (**uplatex**) Version of uptex with etex features.

Comment: but what is pLaTeX?

Comment: @vy32 as I say above it is latex made with the eptex engine so with extra support for japanese

Comment: I see that you explained that `eptex` is a version of `eptex` with `etex` features, but it wasn't clear to me what `(platex)` in parenthesis means.  I guess your notation is confusing to me?

Comment: @vy32 I give the name of the latex format in parenthesis after each tex engine or (-) if the standard distributions do not make a latex format. so pdflatex is latex format made with pdftex and platex is a latex format made with eptex.